# How to format 'for loop' to take on reduce()?

Tags: javascript

```
function validateLineup (lineup) {
    let sumSalary = 0

    for (let i = 0 ; i < lineup.length; i++) {
        sumSalary += lineup[i].salary
        if (sumSalary > 45000) {
            return false
        } 
    }
    return true
}
module.exports = validateLineup
```

What I'm working with^ and would like to format as ternary.
I attempted to format it as ternary but ended up with this and it's not passing tests:

```
let sumSalary = lineup.reduce(function(sum, salary){
    return sum + lineup[i].salary
}, 0)
```

Edit: I want to format this to take on reduce(). Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: What do you mean by `format as ternary`? This does not look the sort of thing i would use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for.

Comment: My brain is fried and I forgot what I was asking. I would like to be able to use reduce() here. Any ideas? Please and thank you.

Comment: Your original solution is better than the one with `reduce`. `reduce` will go over all the items in the array even if the condition `sumSalary > 45000` fails earlier while your original solution will return `false` as soon as the condition fails

Comment: `function validateLineup (lineup) { let sumSalary = lineup.reduce(function(sum, itm){ return sum + itm.salary; }, 0); return sumSalary < 45000`;  } is what you want, but would be better off with original code.

Comment: if it helps, I can link my repo here: https://github.com/kathalonso/perfect-lineup
i'm days late with my homework and for the life of me cannot come up with anything that passes.

Comment: Using reduce here is not very smart: there is no possibility for an early exit. If you have 1000 entries to iterate, and already the first value crosses the 45000 boundary, you perform 999 iterations in vain.

Answer (score 2):

The downside of `reduce` is that you loose the possibility to have an early exit. If your array has 1000 entries, and already the first value crosses the 45000 threshold, you'll still be locked into making those 999 other iterations, without any benefit.

If you're looking for an array function that does the job *with* the possibility for an early exit, then consider `every`:

```js
function validateLineup (lineup) {
    return lineup.every(function({salary}) {
        return (this.sum += salary) <= 45000;
    }, { sum: 0 }); // use `this` for tracking the sum
}

let lineup = [{ salary: 30000}, { salary: 30000}, { salary: 30000}];
console.log("within limits? ", validateLineup(lineup));
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to change `lineup` in your reducer

```
function validateLineup(lineup) {
    let sumSalary = lineup.reduce(function(sum, current){
        return sum + current.salary
    }, 0)
    
    return sumSalary <= 45000
}
```

or if you want it really compact:

```
const validateLineup = lineup => lineup.reduce((sum, {salary}) => sum + salary, 0) <= 45000;
```

Comment: It should be `<= 45000` instead of `> 45000`, return false if the sum is bigger than 45000, true otherwise. Sorry to bother you again

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I don't think it's a good solution bc ... https://imgur.com/a/SCu9znh

Comment: @katalingua try it with sumSalary <= 45000 as ibrahim suggests

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this?

```
function validateLineup(lineup) {
  let sumSalary = lineup.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.salary, 0);
  return sumSalary <= 45000
}
```

Comment: If anyone's free after 7pm new york time to help me out, i will really appreciate it. I done crying all week lol. I'll put up my zoom shortly.

Comment: https://zoom.us/j/6238949381

if anyone's around, come knock on my virtual door!